# Rendering a tensor as image in tensorflow.js

Tags: image, tensor, tensorflow.js

I have an image on which I have applied some preprocessing, after preprocessing the returned image is in form of a tensor.

```
function preprocess(img) {
    let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img)
    const resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tensor, [40, 85]).toFloat()
    const reshape = resized.reshape([1, 40, 85, 3])
    return reshape
}
```

I want to render `reshape` in html. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you're already using `tf.browser.fromPixels(img)`, so why not continue with `tf.browser.toPixels()` :)